# Hierarchical RESTful URL design

Tags: web-services, rest

I have perused the questions asked about this, but I still don't have a definitive answer.

I have an application and would like to build a RESTful API to expose a subset of information. I have three resources:

1. users
2. reports
3. photos

Users have reports and reports have photos. Photos cannot exist outside of reports and reports cannot exist outside of users.

I have designed the following URLs for my requirements

**User login, server responds with token which is sent in the header of all API calls**

```
GET example.com/api/
```

**Get user info**

```
GET example.com/api/users/{username}
```

**Get all user reports**

```
GET example.com/api/users/{username}/reports
```

**Get all photos of a report**

```
GET example.com/api/users/{username}/reports/{report_id}/photos
```

**Add a photo**

```
POST example.com/api/users/{username}/reports/{report_id}/photos
```

**Delete a photo**

```
DELETE example.com/api/users/{username}/reports/{report_id}/photos/{photo_id}
```

**Modify photo description**

```
PUT example.com/api/users/{username}/reports/{report_id}/photos/{photo_id}
```

**Questions**

1. Is it good practice to add a resource id in the URL, i.e. resource/id, or should this rather be added as a query parameter?
2. Is this method of chaining resources, i.e. resource/id/sub-resource/id/etc., acceptable and good or should I put all my resources at the top level and specify its position with query parameters?

Comment: I like what you have but I'm curious why you wouldn't treat photos and reports as as top-level resources.  eg, /reports/{reportid}/authors /reports/{reportid}/photos /photos/{photoid}/authors /photos/{photoid}/reports. I understand your constraints but just curious, why you wouldn't want to drill into the data from different entry points.  What if a report has more than one author - what if you have a report ID or title but not its authors, etc.  No reason you can't have multiple paths to the same resource, but I would recommend informing the user of the canonical URI to each if you do.

Comment: Sidenote: **Restful APIs** should **always** be **versioned** (`example.com/api/…` vs. `example.com/api/1/…`) in order to **avoid URI collisions** with future **API changes**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IMHO you are modelling it well.

Regarding `1` I'd rather go with `resource/id` rather than query param. But one thing you must have in mind when modelling is the cache mechanism by proxy and so on. So do not forget the headers.

I go for query params for filtering and those sorts.

About the login, the credentials should be in the headers, and no specific resource is needed. Just apply per resource security.

Answer (score 13):

Nothing wrong in this design.But this creates long URL which sometime are difficult to understand and the user of the API needs to know the hierarchy.Moreover the consumer of the API need to write more code in little bit non-standard way(Even though it can be done, but will be little messy). Think this from a different perspective
You have three resources and each has its own identity.So if we refactor the above URI's it will looks like below (I am demonstrating only GET)

User Resource:

Get users list

```
  GET example.com/api/users
```

Get specific user

```
  GET example.com/api/users/{username}
```

Report Resource:

Get all reports

```
 GET example.com/api/reports
```

Get a specific report

```
 GET example.com/api/reports/{report_id}
```

Photo Resources

All Photos

```
GET example.com/api/photos
```

Specific Photo

```
GET example.com/api/photos/{photo_id}
```

User All Reports

```
GET example.com/api/reports?username={userName}
```

Specific report of a user

```
GET example.com/api/report?username={userName}&report_id={reportId}
```

User All Photos

```
GET example.com/api/photos?username={userName}
```

User All Photos for a report id (You may not need user Name if report_id is unique irrespective of the user, which will further simplify the URI)

```
GET example.com/api/photos?username={userName}&report_id={reportId}
```

All photos of a report

```
GET example.com/api/photos?report_id={reportId}
```

This simplifies the understanding and more standard code can be written on the consumer side using this approach.

Comment: I like your example. If I want to add a photo is correct to pass id of the parent (User) in the body json? example POST example.com/api/photos  { "id":"user_id_111","photo":"my_photo"}

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong with your scheme.

Most frameworks nowadays use a similar standard for specifying url's (like Django).

In my personal opinion, it makes the URL more readable and a bit nicer for the user.