# Django REST framework filtering views

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I managed to get data from the tables `MemberDeclareRecept` and `Member` with the following config files. Here I am looking for the `MemberDeclareRecept.pk`. But how can I get all the data if I search the `Member.CoId` instead? 
The `MemberSearchByCode` view gives all the members in the table but I can't get the specific member.

Here are my models

```
class Member(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=40,null=True)
    FirstName = models.CharField(max_length=40,null=True)
    DateBirth = models.DateField(,null=True)
    CoId = models.CharField(max_length=6,null=True)

class MemberDeclareRecept(models.Model):
    SyMember=models.ForeignKey(Member,verbose_name='Name member ',null=True,related_name='Member')
    DateDeclareRecept=models.DateField(('Date received',null=True)
```

And the serializers that are being used

```
class MemberDeclareSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    member = serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only=True)
    SyRecept=serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = MemberDeclareRecept
        fields=('id','member','SyRecept')
```

And the views that I am currently using

```
class MemberDeclareDetail(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset=MemberDeclareRecep.objects.all()
    serializer_class =MemberDeclareSerializer
    def get_object(self,pk):
        try:
            return self.queryset.get(pk=pk)
        except MemberDeclareRecep.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def get(self, request, pk,format=None):
        entries = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = MemberDeclareSerializer(entries)
        return Response(serializer.data)

class MemberSearchByCode(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class =MemberSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        member=self.request.QUERY_PARAMS.get(Co_id',None)
        if membre is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(member__Name=member
        return queryset
```

Comment: Missing some extra info: the version of DRF. there are several ways to implement filters in this list view. see http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering

Comment: Hi Michel. I user REST 3.0

Comment: I've found this to solve my problem :  class MemberSearch(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class=MemberDeclareSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):

        member=self.kwargs['Co_id']
        return member_declare_recept.objects.filter(member__Co_id=member)  Any comments or suggestions?

Comment: That will do indeed!  Good you solved it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears as though you've found an answer, [based on the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27873984/django-rest-framework-query#comment44388368_27873984), and it's included below.

```
class MemberSearch(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class=MemberDeclareSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        member = self.kwargs['Co_id']

        return member_declare_recept.objects.filter(member__Co_id=member)
```

It is important to note that this is not filtering the queryset based on query parameters, this is filtering it based on parameters present in the url. If you were filtering it based on query parameters, which is useful if you will need to get a list of all objects at once, the url that you would be using would be like

```
/api/members/?company=[co_id]
```

Which would make the company id optional. In your case though, the id is being embedded within the url itself. This is typically [referred to as hierarchal urls](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7833548/359284), and it's [generally not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7104578/359284), but your urls end up like

```
/api/company/[co_id]/members
```

Which is preferable for some, and even required in certain cases.

---

Now, if you wanted to use the query parameter instead of the url parameter for filtering, only a slight change would be required in your code.

```
class MemberSearch(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class=MemberDeclareSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        company_id = self.request.query_parameters.get('company', None)

        if not company_id:
            return member_declare_recept.objects.all()

        return member_declare_recept.objects.filter(member__Co_id=company_id)
```

This has the additional advantage of also being support directly through [django-filter and the `DjangoFilterBackend`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#djangofilterbackend).

Comment: Thanks Kevin for the formatting, grammar and recommendations ! This article is better now for sharing.